# Does anyone know what happened to IPluralizer, ICandidateNamingService and CandidateNamingService in EF Core 3.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I just updated to Entity Framework Core 3.0 and the following code no longer compiles. It looks like
IPluralizer, ICandidateNamingService and CandidateNamingService no longer exist.

Does anyone know what is the new recommended approach for customising the generation of entities via Add-Migration InitialCreate?

```
public class CustomDesignTimeServices : IDesignTimeServices
{
    public void ConfigureDesignTimeServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<ICandidateNamingService, CustomCandidateNamingService>();
       services.AddSingleton<IPluralizer, CustomPluralizer>();
    }
}

public class CustomPluralizer : IPluralizer
{
    public string Pluralize(string name)
    {
        return Inflector.Inflector.Pluralize(name) ?? name;
    }
    public string Singularize(string name)
    {
        return Inflector.Inflector.Singularize(name) ?? name;
    }
}

public class CustomCandidateNamingService : CandidateNamingService
{
    public override string GetDependentEndCandidateNavigationPropertyName(IForeignKey foreignKey)
    {
        if (foreignKey.PrincipalKey.IsPrimaryKey())
            return foreignKey.PrincipalEntityType.ShortName();

        return base.GetDependentEndCandidateNavigationPropertyName(foreignKey);
    }
}
```

Comment: You might need a reference to the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design` NuGet package.

Comment: Yep am referencing this package but the types seem to have gone missing when upgrading to 3.0

Comment: See 3.0 breaking changes - [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design is now a DevelopmentDependency package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#dip).

Comment: @IvanStoev Any word on how to do this in EF 5? I've got IDesignTimeServices from Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design, but I'm not finding CandidateNamingService anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

I got IPluralizer reference working again in .NET 6, by

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.1.9">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
  <!-- Remove IncludeAssets to allow compiling against the assembly -->
  <!--<IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>-->
</PackageReference>
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/services